# Creating a sequence which values are a mix of character and numbers

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.1 and would like to create a sequence which I can use as primary key and which should look like this:

```
| entity_id_seq |
-----------------
|         X0001 |
|         X0002 |
           ....
|         X0123 |
```

and `nextval( 'entity_id_seq' )` would return `'X0124'`.

Any idea's how and if this is possible with pure Postgres?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use it in the column definition for automatically incremented key? Do you want to have it always like 'X[0-9]{4}'?

Comment: @SzymonGuz Both questions answered with yes :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should be fine:

Create the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE special_seq;
```

Create a function, or not:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
nextval_special()
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
    SELECT 'X'||to_char(nextval('special_seq'), 'FM0000'); 
$$;
```

Now check if it works:

```
SELECT nextval_special() FROM generate_series(1,10);

 nextval_special 
-----------------
 X0001
 X0002
 X0003
 X0004
 X0005
 X0006
 X0007
 X0008
 X0009
 X0010
(10 rows)
```

Now you can create the table using the above function:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval_special(),
    a int
);
```

or just without function with the simple query from the function:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'X'||to_char(nextval('special_seq'), 'FM0000'),
    a int
);
```

Answer (score 2):

We could make a function that would make use nextval and prepend the X to it. Something like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION nextseq() RETURNS text
AS 
begin 
return 'X'||lpad(nextval( 'entity_id_seq',4,'0' );
end;
```