# How to create serial number for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, rubygems

I want to create ticket number by serial number, eg. T-0001, T-0002, T-0003,
for ruby on rails project. How to make this?

```
Admission.transaction do
  cus = @admission.customer
  cus.inpatient_id = cus.inpatient_id || "I-%.6d" % cus.id
  cus.save
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you show code?

Comment: you need to implement custom method in your model. in which model you want to create this serial number? give more details

Comment: [Admission.transaction do
        cus = @admission.customer
        cus.inpatient_id = cus.inpatient_id || "I-%.6d" %
        cus.save
      end] 
 I want to add serail number code in cus.inpatient_id likes that T-0001, T-0002, T-0003. How to create this?

Comment: Do you get any errors or unexpected results when running your code?

Comment: Not errors get, but ' cus.inpatient_id = cus.inpatient_id || "I-%.6d" % cus.id' generate likes that I-0005, 5 is customer id. I want to create start with I-0001. if customer has I-0001, but customer has not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is just sample to generate your required formatted series on range:

```
> (0..5).map{|e| "T-#{e.to_s.rjust(4, "0")}"}
#=> ["T-0000", "T-0001", "T-0002", "T-0003", "T-0004", "T-0005"]
```

If you are using `PG` / `MySQL` you can use object's `id` for unique number (`ID`- primary key is always serialize and unique)

**UPDATE:** as per [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980259/how-to-create-serial-number-for-ruby-on-rails/51980688#comments-51980259#comment-90910663):

```
Admission.transaction do 
  cus = @admission.customer 
  cus.inpatient_id = cus.inpatient_id || "T-#{cus.id.to_s.rjust(4, "0")}"
  cus.save 
end
```

Comment: _"you can use object's id for unique number"_ – depends on your database. Try to generate a number sequence from MongoDB's ObjectIds :-)

Comment: It's insert data into database as '["T-0000", "T-0001", "T-0002", "T-0003", "T-0004", "T-0005"]', I want to create one row per one ticket, eg, 
[id = 1, ticket_id =  T-0000], 
[id = 2, ticket_id = T0002].

Comment: @Stefan : OP doesn't want to store as `id` (primary-key) , but instead he wants to store in field.

Comment: @GaganGami yes, I understand that. You suggested to generate the number from the object's id, right? If you were using MongoDB, your object ids would look like `5b7e9f88d32a6d888b789d61` – it's kind of hard to generate a numerical sequence out of that.

Comment: @Stefan, oh I got your concern, updated answer by specifying DBs

Answer (score 3):

Most rails servers are multi-threaded. Meaning many requests will be processed in parallel. You can imagine two processes trying to create a new serial number at the same point in time - duplicate ticket numbers! - not what we expect for sure.

It is better we delegate this task of creating ids to the database itself. So instead of the default auto-increment ids (1,2,3,4...), we will tell database to create ids in this format (`T-0001`, `T-0002`, ...). This can be achieved using [custom sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html). I am assuming postgres database here, but should be same for [mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-generate-a-sequence-in-mysql).

First create sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ticket_seq;
```

But sequences don't allow strings so we convert them to strings and format them:

```
SELECT 'T-'||to_char(nextval('ticket_seq'), 'FM0000');
```

This will return values like `T-0001`, `T-0002` ...

Note: We have just created a sequence, you need to tell database to use this sequence instead.

Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10736871/3507206